# Inconsistency in results of calling Get-AuthenticodeSignature from PowerShell, often says NotSigned

Tags: powershell, authenticode

I have a number of PowerShell files code signed during build.

I'm getting different signature status depending how I call `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem | ForEach { Get-AuthenticodeSignature $_.Name }

SignerCertificate                         Status  Path
-----------------                         ------  ----
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   CleanUpdateParameters.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   CreateApplication.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   DeleteApplication.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   ProvisionApplicationType.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   UnprovisionApplicationType.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid   UpdateParameters.ps1
```

Everything looks good. But here's the results when I ry to validate the files using either binary content:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem | ForEach { Get-AuthenticodeSignature -Content ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.FullName)) -SourcePathOrExtension $_.Name }

SignerCertificate                         Status     Path
-----------------                         ------     ----
                                          NotSigned  CleanUpdateParameters.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid      CreateApplication.ps1
                                          NotSigned  DeleteApplication.ps1
                                          NotSigned  ProvisionApplicationType.ps1
                                          NotSigned  UnprovisionApplicationType.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid      UpdateParameters.ps1
```

or string content:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem | ForEach { Get-AuthenticodeSignature -Content ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName))) -SourcePathOrExtension $_.Name }

SignerCertificate                         Status      Path
-----------------                         ------      ----
                                          NotSigned   CleanUpdateParameters.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid       CreateApplication.ps1
                                          NotSigned   DeleteApplication.ps1
                                          NotSigned   ProvisionApplicationType.ps1
                                          NotSigned   UnprovisionApplicationType.ps1
E36170335E3DD78B6CDF1594B0D164F7C8A7B324  Valid       UpdateParameters.ps1
```

I spent a week already on this and cannot wrap my head around what's causing this discrepancy/inconsistency. And I do have to make it working as my application ('client') receives the scripts from a service ('server') as a string and has to validate the validity of the content.

Comment: Normal files may be signed one of two ways: embedded signature, or catalog signing. I believe this may be what you're seeing. Get-AuthenticodeSignature works fine for files with embedded signatures; but it reports catalog-signed files as being unsigned.

Comment: @Rthomas529: what puzzles me the most is the inconsistency. All files are getting signed during build basically in one shot. So I'd expect same mode used for all of them.

Comment: If you really want to know, work backwards. First determine the type of signature they have. If they aren't the same investigate the discrepancy. If they are the same I would say maybe this is a module issue. Try here https://github.com/cobbr/PSReflect-Functions/blob/master/Examples/Get-DigitalSignature.ps1

Comment: @Rthomas529: that script doesn't work for me unfortunately (Windows 10 x64update 10/2018), throws an error on every WinAPI call

Comment: @mklement0: to answer your question "why -Content?": my client receives the the script from server and I wanted to validate its signature on-the-fly, without saving it to a temporary folder. Which didn't work first at all but after some manipulations with encoding (ASCII thus no BOM) worked. Now I'm going to resave the scripts in UTF-16LE and try all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** as of pwsh 7.4.0, this bug has been fixed ([fix PR here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/18774)). However, many people will be using prior versions for a while, and 5.1 is stuck with this bug, so the workarounds below will remain valuable.

---

Sadly, **`Get-AuthenticodeSignature -Content` only recognizes byte arrays if they represent "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoded characters** - any other encoding is misrepresented as `NotSigned` in the output.
See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3408).

The implication of your symptoms is that only scripts `CreateApplication.ps1` and `UpdateParameters.ps1` are UTF-16LE-encoded.

If you wanted to use `-Content` with all of your scripts:

- *either*: transcode all your script files to UTF-16LE (save them with that encoding).
- *or*: pass expression `([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetPreamble() +[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName)))` to `-Content`, i.e., manually convert the file content to UTF-16LE bytes; note the need to explicitly prepend the BOM (preamble)).

As you've observed, using (implied) parameter `-FilePath` - i.e. passing a *file path* and letting `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` itself read its *contents* - is *not* subject to this encoding restriction - as long as PowerShell can infer the script file's encoding per the usual rules, signature verification succeeds.

Comment: PowerShell runner in C# accepts script content as a string, not as a file. So I feed server response directly into it, without creating a temp file. So would like to do the same during signature validation. Hope this explain my intend better now.